# jQuery selector depending on the value of the span tag

Tags: jquery

Supposing I have this HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv">
<p>
<span>My first span</span>
</p>
<p>
<span>My second span</span>
</p>
<p>
<span>My third span</span>
</p>
```

My problem is that I'm appending HTML to the p tags:

```
$('#mydiv p').append('<img src="http://example.com/myimage.png">');
```

But I only want to append to the second p with the span tag text "My second span" (or any other p tags with their respective span text depending on my application). so this is the resulting HTML after appending:

```
<p>
<span>My second span</span><img src="http://example.com/myimage.png">
</p>
```

One limitation is that I cannot edit the original HTML sourcecode so I cannot assign class or ID selectors to them.

How would I revise my jQuery selectors to target a specific p with the specific span text? Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with the :contains() selector.

```
$("#mydiv span:contains('My second span')")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#mydiv p:eq(1)').append('<img src="http://example.com/myimage.png">');
```

Edit:

With your updated question, the selector suggested by Daveo's answer above should do it. However, in that case you need to use `after` instead of `append`:

```
$("#mydiv span:contains('My second span')").after('<img src="http://example.com/myimage.png">');
```

Comment: Thanks,is it possible to include the span text value for a more accurate selector?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that, instead you could assign a class to the `p` elements which will contain the appended html.

Comment: One limitation is that I cannot edit the original HTML sourcecode. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `$('#mydiv p:nth-child(2)')` (i.e. select the second child with `p` tag of `mydiv`)

Surely you can select that element by hard-coded text, but I don't think that is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Assume from explanation you want this text specific. Can use `:contains(text)` selector.

```
var txt="My second span" ;
/* selector finds the span, parent() moves back up to "p" tag*/
$('#mydiv p span:contains('+txt+')').parent().append('<img ...>');
```

API reference: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Not clear if it has to be filtered to only second span containing this text